# найти css selector по тексту

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать селектор для следующего элемента:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал вот так: span:contains('Mozah'), но не получается

Comment: в Google chrome вообще не могу составить селектор по тексту. Также не работает div:contains('my text') для <div>my text</div>!!!! Что не так делаю, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: НАШЕЛ : //div[contains(text(), 'General Cargo & Dry Bulk')]

Answer (score 1):

У вас не работал вариант  div:contains('my text'), потому эта конструкция работает только с jQuery

```js
$("span:contains('Ьщяфр')").text("Mozah");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Ьщяфр</span>
```